# SQL Server : Encrypt / Protect stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2

I am just wondering any good tools or software that you can recommend me to protect / encrypt my stored procedure that was developed on SQL Server 2008 R2 ?

I read about create stored procedure with encryption and is it possible to get it decrypted in case I have bugs in the program?

Also, came across CLR but I don't think I want to create a stored procedure in Visual Studio environment. Or I could be wrong.

Hope you can give me some advise while I am still researching on this topic.

Final objective would be, I don't want people to view my stored procedure and steal it for own use.

Thanks.

Comment: A admin can always decrypt stored procs

Comment: So, anyone with sa rights can decrypt it. Correct ?

Comment: Since few year ago, I remember that there were some tools to decrypt SPs, not sure if it still is possible nor not. Anyway, if you are going to use lots of CLR only for this reason, it's not a good idea. CLRs degrade the performance vs T-SQL SPs.

Comment: I think it is harder to deploy using CLR. If not mistaken, we need to create CLR outside SSMS. I am not a .NET person, so I don't really know how to use Visual Studio to create the CLR.

Comment: "CLRs degrade the performance vs T-SQL SPs" - that sweeping statement is incorrect. There are uses of CLR SP's that drastically improve performance (such as string handling)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to hide the script of a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554714/i-want-to-hide-the-script-of-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @user3015739 SQL Server's `WITH ENCRYPTION` is actually mild obfuscation. It *can* be decrypted by users with adequate rights. This may or may not be enough for your needs.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, do you have any example on how to decrypt it ? I want to test how easy it is to decrypt a function. I tried Google but not much success.

Answer (score 2):

It's not free, but you could give [SqlShield](http://www.sql-shield.com/index.php) a try

> SQL Shield is a built-in tool for MSSQL, SQL Express and MSDE servers that offers hacker-proof encryption for triggers, views and procedures

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use `WITH ENCRYPTION`?
For example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #EncryptSP
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
SELECT TOP 10 City
FROM Person.Address
GO
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187926%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Mountaineer, if I use WITH ENCRYPTION, only user with sa account or sysadmin can decrypt it. Correct ?

Comment: You need third party tools to decrypt.  A summary explanation on "with encryption" here.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/01/sql-server-explanation-of-with-encryption-clause-for-stored-procedure-and-user-defined-functions/

Comment: If you need to make changes to an encrypted SP then keep a copy of the sql code

Answer (score -2):

you can use [dbforge decryptor](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqldecryptor/) for decryption.